# Meta og:image not working for facebook and doesn't detect preview sharing link image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Unfortunately the meta og:image URL for facebook is not working for me. To be exact it is not detecting the preview image when sharing the link. I have tested several times through the facebook sharing debugger and unfortunately it does not work. I also went through several threads on this forum on the topic, no solution helped.

I get

```
    Invalid Image Content Type
    Provided og:image URL, https://delightart.co/static/media/delightartco.jpg could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type.
```

```
<!-- Open Graph / Facebook -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://delightart.co">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Delightartco - Brand Stylist & Web designer">
    <meta property="og:description" content="DelightartCo helps passionate coaches and entrepreneurs build their online identity through: shaping the personal brand,Designing and launching custom websites, Producing chic and trendy content on social media">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://delightart.co/static/media/delightartco.jpg" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1279801235808489">
```

Comment: It seems your server software or your hosting service may be refusing the request for the image from FB. I ran both your URL and your og:image URL through [Rex Swain's HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) and your site responded with a 500 to both requests. Your site does respond to Twitter as well as the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) and your site responds to those bots, so your problem seems to be limited.

Comment: This helped me to find the issue. My og:image URLs did not contain the "www" domain prefix and the fb crawler got redirected by the web server each time.